# Fabius function and equivalent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, probability-distributions, special-functions

The [Fabius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) $F$ can be defined on $[0,1]$ by

- $F(0)=0$
- $F(1)=1$
- on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ $F'(x)=2F(2x)$
- on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ $F'(x)=2F(2(1-x))$

It's a known example of a not analytic $C^\infty$ function.

The Fabius function can also be defined as the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the random variable $X$ such that
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}U_i$$
where $U_i$ are independent random variables uniform on $[0,1]$.

Is it possible to find a usual function $f$ such that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x)}{f(x)}=1$$

Some functions like $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ could be good candidates, but I don't really know how to find such a function, or given a function $f$, how to compute the limit.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\!\left(-\log_2\!x\right)\,\sqrt{x^{\log_2\!x+1}}}\int_0^1 \frac{1-F(t)}{t^{\log_2\!x+1}}\,dt$ looks like a plausible candidate. It is real-analytic and we can show that the equality $f(x)=F(x)$ holds exactly on an infinite set of points in any neighborhood of $x=0$. Its graph suggests that the required limit holds, but I still have to fill some gaps in my proof.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov If you are using F itself, it's not really useful, because you can just say $f(x)=F(x)$ or $f(x)=2\int F(2t)dt$. But your expressions are really complex and puzzling 

Comment: The question ask for a "usual" function asymptotic to $F(x)$. It is not really clear what "usual" means, so I interpreted it as "analytic". Although my example is defined in terms of an integral of $F(x)$, it is an analytic function (in some vicinity of $x=0$, but excluding that point itself; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495466/an-integral-involving-a-smooth-function). Of course, it would be much more interesting to find an elementary(-ish) asymptotic function, not defined in terms of $F(x)$; I tried to do that for quite some time, but I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: Here is an alternative form, not involving the Fabius function at all (it is the same analytic function as in my first comment above):$\displaystyle f(x) = \left.\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \, x^{\frac{a-1}2}}{2^{a\,n+\binom n2} \, \Gamma\left(a+n\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}t_k\,\left(2k+1\right)^{a+n-1}\right|_{a\,=-\log_2\!x, \,\, t_0 = 1, \,\, t_k = (-1)^k \, t_{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}}$

Answer (score 3):

Based oh [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4354570/19661) answer, the asymptotic of the Fabius function for $x\to0^+$:
$$\small F(x)\sim \frac{1}{2^{7/12} \sqrt{\pi \, x}}\, \exp \left(\frac{1}{\log 2} \left(\gamma _1+\frac{\gamma_0^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-q-\frac{q^2}{2}\right)\right),\quad q=W_{-1}(-x \log2),$$
where $W_{-1}(x)$ is the non-principal real-valued branch of the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#:%7E:text=When%20dealing%20with%20real%20numbers%20only%2C%20the%20two%20branches%20W0%20and%20W%E2%88%921%20suffice), and $\gamma_n$ are the [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) (in particular, $\gamma_0$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) $\gamma$).