# Conjectured formula for the Fabius function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, conjectures, experimental-mathematics, q-analogs

The [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) is the unique  function ${\bf F}:\mathbb R\to[-1, 1]$ satisfying the following conditions:

- a functional–integral equation$\require{action}
  \require{enclose}{^{\texttip{\dagger}{a poet or philosopher could say "it knows and replays its own future"}}}$ $\displaystyle{\bf F}(x)={\small\int_0^{2{\tiny\text{ }}x}}{\bf F}\left(t\right)dt,\,$ and
- a normalization condition ${\bf F}(1)=1.$

It is noteworthy that despite being [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) (class $C^\infty$)${^{\texttip{\dagger}{i.e. continuous and having continuous derivatives of any order}}}$ everywhere, ${\bf F}(x)$ is not [real-analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Real_versus_complex_analytic_functions) at any point $x\ge0$ — its [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) there is either [divergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series), or a polynomial with a finite number of terms.${^{\texttip{\dagger}{the latter happens at dyadic rational points}}}$

Unlike some other functions that appear specifically constructed for that purpose, the Fabius function naturally occurs in research of several seemingly unrelated problems — perhaps, this is why it has been discovered and re-discovered independently many times by several mathematicians. It also has some practical applications in computational mathematics.

[image: Fabius function]

The Fabius function ${\bf F}(x)$ is constant $0$ for all $x\le0,$  but some authors prefer to define it only on $[0,\infty)$ or only on $[0,1].$ Some authors study a very closely related Rvachev${^{\texttip{\dagger}{also variously spelled as Rvachëv or Rvachyov, a.k.a. "atomic function"}}}$ function $\operatorname{up}(x)$ defined as $\operatorname{up}(x) = {\bf F}(x+1)$ for $-1\le x\le1$ and $\operatorname{up}(x) = 0$ otherwise.

It is known that the Fabius function assumes rational values at [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) arguments — efficient algorithms to compute those values have been published or posted online, and have been discussed on this site.[$^{[1]}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07999)[$\!^{[2]}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442)[$\!^{[3]}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06487)[$\!^{[4]}$](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/s51/s51.pdf)[$\!^{[5]}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240687/19661)[$\!^{[6]}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218832/19661)[$\!^{[7]}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2497242/19661)[$\!^{[8]}$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120331/7288)[$\!^{[9]}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261649/9550)

I have been looking for a non-recursive, self-contained formula for the Fabius function for quite a long time. After lots of experimentation and looking for patterns in its values I came up with a conjectured empirical formula. Let${^{\texttip{\dagger}{the superscript  is just an index here, not to be confused with a power}}}$
$$\mathscr F^m_n = \frac1{2^{n^2}\left(\frac12;{\tiny\text{ }}\frac12\right)_n}\,\sum _{k=0}^n\frac{\binom n k_{1/2}}{2^{{\tiny\text{ }}k{\tiny\text{ }}(k-1)}(n+k)!}\,\sum _{\ell=0}^{2^k{\tiny\text{ }}m-1}\,(-1)^{s_2\left(\ell\right)}\,\left(\ell-2^km+\tfrac12\right)^{n+k}{\small,}\tag{$\small\spadesuit$}$$
where $k,\,\ell,\,m,\,n$ are non-negative integers, $\displaystyle\small\left(a;{\tiny\text{ }}q\right)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-a{\tiny\text{ }}q^k)$ is the [*q*-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/q-Pochhammer_symbol)${^{\texttip{\dagger}{it assumes only rational values in this formula}}}$, ${\binom n k}_q=\displaystyle\small\frac{\left(q;{\tiny\text{ }}q\right)_n}{\left(q;{\tiny\text{ }}q\right)_k\left(q;{\tiny\text{ }}q\right)_{n-k}}\vphantom{\Huge|}$ is the [*q*-binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/q-binomial_coefficient)${^{\texttip{\dagger}{it assumes only rational values in this formula}}}$, and $s_2(n)\vphantom{\Huge|}$ is the [sum of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) [binary digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)${^{\texttip{\dagger}{i.e. the number of 1's in the base-2 representation}}}$ of $n$ (note that $(-1)^{s_2\left(n\right)} = t_n\vphantom{\Huge|}$ is just the signed version of the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence), satisfying recurrence $t_0 = 1,\,t_n = (-1)^n \, t_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor};\vphantom{\Huge|}$ see also[${^{[10]}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_number)[${\!^{[11]}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odious_number)[${\!^{[12]}}$](https://oeis.org/A010060)).

I conjecture that for all non-negative integers $m,\,n,$ the following identity holds:
$${\bf F}\!\left({\small\frac m{2^n}}\right)=\mathscr F^m_n.\tag{$\small\diamondsuit$}$$
Note that there is no requirement for $\frac m{2^n}$ to be a proper irreducible fraction — it might well be that $m$ is even, or $m>2^n$. I have not been able to rigorously prove it yet, but it produces exact rational values that agree with those computed using known correct algorithms for all dyadic rational arguments I have tried. Of course, this formula did not just appear out of the blue — its structure was inspired by known algorithms, and it went a long way to this relatively concise form (at some point it had about $5$ levels of nested summations/products).

- Can we prove that $\small(\diamondsuit)$ is indeed a correct representation of the Fabius function at dyadic rationals?
- If the conjecture is difficult to tackle at once, we can try to at least prove that the function defined by $\small(\spadesuit)$ shares some known properties with the Fabius function, e.g.:

  - $0\le\mathscr F^m_n\le1,$
  - $\mathscr F^m_n = \mathscr F^{2{\tiny\text{ }}m}_{n+1}\vphantom{\Large|}$ — the result is the same across all representations of a rational number $\frac m{2^n}$,
  - $\mathscr F^m_n = 1-\mathscr F^{(2^n-m)}_n\vphantom{\Large|}$ for all $\small0\le m\le2^{n}$ — rotation symmetry,
  - $\mathscr F^m_n = \mathscr F^{(2^{n+1}-m)}_n\vphantom{\Large|}$ for all $\small0\le m\le2^{n+1}$ — reflection symmetry,
  - for a fixed $n,$ and $\small0\le m\le2^n$ the values of $\mathscr F^m_n\vphantom{\Large|}$ strictly increase,
  - all points $\small\left(\frac m{2^n},\,\mathscr F^m_n\right)\vphantom{\Large|}$ lie on a continuous curve — for any convergent sequence of dyadic rationals $\frac m{2^n}\vphantom{\Large|}$, the sequence of corresponding values $\mathscr F^m_n\vphantom{\Large|}$ also converges.

---

If the conjecture $\small(\diamondsuit)$ it true, then for all $0\le x\le1$ (not necessary rational)
$${\bf F}\!\left(x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac1{2^{n^2}\left(\frac12;{\tiny\text{ }}\frac12\right)_n}\,\sum _{k=0}^n\frac{\binom n k_{1/2}}{2^{{\tiny\text{ }}k{\tiny\text{ }}(k-1)}(n+k)!}\,\sum _{\ell=0}^{\left\lfloor2^{n+k}{\tiny\text{ }}x-1\right\rfloor}\,(-1)^{s_2\left(\ell\right)}\,\left(\ell-2^{n+k}{\tiny\text{ }}x+\tfrac12\right)^{n+k}.\tag{$\small\heartsuit$}$$
For dyadic rational $x$ the limit is trivial, because the sequence under the limit becomes constant for large enough $n$. Also, there is a known series (by Rvachev) that expresses values of the Fabius function for all $0\le x\le1$ via its values at negative powers of $2$:
$${\bf F}\!\left(x\right)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor 2^n{\tiny\text{ }}x\right\rfloor }-1}{2}\,(-1)^{s_2\left(\lfloor2^n{\tiny\text{ }}x\rfloor\right)}\;\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^{\frac{k{\tiny\text{ }}(k+1)}2}}{k!}\,\left(x-2^{-n}\left\lfloor 2^n{\tiny\text{ }}x\right\rfloor\right)^k\;{\bf F}\!\left(2^{{\tiny\text{ }}k-n}\right).\tag{$\small\clubsuit$}$$
Again, for dyadic rational $x$ this series terminates after a finite number of terms, producing an exact rational value.

Comment: The equation means $F$ can be chosen as we want on $[1,2]$., can you explain why $0 \le F(x) \le F(1)=1$ implies the solution is unique ?

Comment: @reuns To better understand your reasoning — could you provide a pair of distinct functions that you think would be a counterexample to the uniqueness? For the proof of the uniqness you can look into https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442 by Dr. Juan Arias de Reyna — it is the reference [$^{[2]}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442) in my post (for me the proof looks solid). Note that he deals with the Rvachev function there, but it is just a shifted and truncated on the right variant of the Fabius function. If you can provide a valid counterexample, it would mean there is some error in the paper.

Comment: Interesting to see you active again here on MSE. Nevertheless, (+1) as it is an quite difficult (however, fascinating) task to solve.

Comment: *its Taylor series there is either divergent* - That should not constitute a [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generality_of_algebra).

Comment: You might want to consider posing this question to the MO community.

Answer (score 14):

In this answer, whereas the conjectured formula will not be confirmed so far, a simpler non-recursive, explicit formula for the Fabius function will be offered, which is expressed in terms similar to, but simpler than, those in the conjectured formula.

As noted in the  [Wikipedia article on the Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function), on the interval $I:=[0,1]$ the Fabius function coincides with the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of 
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}U_j,$$
where the $U_j$'s are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $I$. So, for each $x\in I$ 
$$F(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x),\tag{1}$$
where $F_n$ is the cdf of $\sum_{j=1}^n 2^{-j}U_j$.

Next (see e.g. [formula (2.2)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06406v1)), for any real $x$
$\newcommand\vp{\varepsilon}$
\begin{equation}
 F_n(x)=\text{vol}_n(I^n\cap H_{n;c^{(n)},x})
 =\frac1{n!\prod_1^n c_i}\,\sum_{\vp\in\{0,1\}^n}(-1)^{|\vp|}\,
 \big(x-c^{(n)}\cdot\vp\big)_+^n,  
\end{equation}
where $\text{vol}_n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$, $H_{n;b,x}:=\{v\in\mathbb R^n\colon b\cdot v\le x\}$, $c^{(n)}:=(c_1,\dots,c_n)$, $c_j:=2^{-j}$, $|\vp|:=\vp_1+\dots+\vp_n$, $\cdot$ denotes the dot product, and $t_+^n:=\max(0,t)^n$. So, for $x\in I$
\begin{equation}
 F_n(x)=\frac{2^{n(n+1)/2}}{n!}\,\sum_{y\in D_{n,x}}(-1)^{s(y)}\,
 \big(x-y\big)^n, \tag{2} 
\end{equation}
where $D_{n,x}$ is the set of all dyadic numbers in $[0,x]$ of the form $m2^{-n}$ for integers $m$, and $s(y)$ is the sum of the binary digits of $y$.

So, this answer consists of formulas (1) and (2).

---

Some of the differences between (1)--(2) and the conjectured formula are as follows:

- The main conjectured formula for $F(x)$ is stated only for dyadic numbers $x$, and then extended to all values of $x$ by the continuity of $F$.
- The expression in the OP for $F(x)$ for dyadic $x$ contains a double summation and a number of $q$-Pochhammer symbols (I have had no experience with those symbols).

N.B.: this answer is cross-posted, with some edits, from [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351004/a-non-recursive-explicit-formula-for-the-fabius-function/351005#351005).